# How to ship different React bundles for Mobile and Desktop versions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm working on a React project that's mobile first, and I'm using Material-UI to design my components. My mobile/desktop components render using material-ui's `<Hidden>` element to figure out if they're needed to render or not.

I'm obviously reluctant to ship all the extra code when not needed on either mobile or desktop, but I do not see many discussions on how to achieve this. I started thinking about lazy loading my components so they never render if not needed, but that might help my performance by a tiny bit, not with my issue of shipping unnecessary code, right? Are there any preferred approach to this which might only include the front end since my backend is running serverless on Firebase?

Comment: most projects use a .ios.jsx .mobile.jsx .desktop.jsx  approach, but you can also use process.env.PLATFORM environment variable to control a webpack import

Comment: soo webpack will be able to ship only the code required for ios and desktop? Also, I thought webpack doesn't even exist once you build and ship your bundles?

Comment: Depneds if you are talking about lazy loading resources, or not compiling them into your bundle

Comment: You'll want to look at code splitting.  It doesn't have to be webpack.  It's just that webpack is the most common so most of the resources and examples for webpack are easier to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Create separated files for your platform or project types based on using extensions:

```
Popup.mobile.tsx // example file for mobile
Popup.desktop.tsx // example file for desktop
```

In using this sample `Popup` component you should add just this line:

```js
import Popup from '[path-to-component]/Popup'; // <--- LOOK! do not add extra extensions here, just the name part
```

Also, add the pre-extension name in a ENV variable like `ENV_TYPE` in your `.env` file:

```
// .env file

ENV_TYPE=mobile
```

Or

```
// .env file

ENV_TYPE=desktop
```

And then add the this configuration in you Webpack:

```js
const envExtensionDetector = (envType, extensions) => [
  ...extensions.map(ext => `.${envType}${ext}`),
  ...extensions,
];

~~~

// webpack configuration

export default {
  resolve: {
    extensions: envExtensionDetector(process.env.ENV_TYPE, [".js", ".jsx", ".css", ".ts", ".tsx"]),
  },
  //...
};
```